# C DLL. How to import in C#

Tags: c#, c

I've to import a C DLL in C# and have that function:

```
set_pin (IN char* str_user, IN char* str_old_pin, IN char* str_new_pin)
```

How to write that in c#? and what's the meaning of the "IN"?

Comment: The term to look for is "P/Invoke" (Platform Invoke). I am far from an expert in that, but I am sure, it's what you are looking for. To explain it in detail would be too broad here. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Use [DllImport], the arguments are *string*.  We can't guess at the return type and calling convention.  The latter is usually Cdecl.  `IN` is SAL annotation that means that you don't have to worry about the function changing the strings you pass.  So you don't have to use StringBuilder, a simple string will do.

Answer (score 4):

`IN` means that the parameter is being used to supply data to the method, and is not being used to return data *from* the method.

Because the data is only being passed TO the method, you can just declare the parameters as `string` - but you may  need to know in which format the method is expecting the strings - are they UTF8, UTF16, ANSI etc?

Once you know the required string format, you can specify it in the P/Invoke declaration for the method (or choose `CharSet.Auto`, which generally means "ANSI"):

```
[DllImport("your.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall))]
public static extern bool set_pin(string str_user, string str_old_pin, string str_new_pin);
```

Just try it with "CharSet.Auto" and don't worry about using something different unless it doesn't work!

Note that you didn't specify the return type of the method, so I've just made it `bool` as an example.

You may also need to specify the calling convention if it isn't the standard `StdCall`.

See [the calling convention enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention?view=netframework-4.8) for details.

Also see [this Microsoft article for documentation on writing P/Invoke specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke).

Comment: Best not to panic the user about the encoding, never utf16 and there is no difference between ansi and utf8 for a pin.